# IFormFile properties in viewmodel null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET core app with files uploading page. Here is a part of View code:

```
<form asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" id="movie-update-form">
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Image</label><br />
        <img id="preview-image" src="" style="width:200px; height:120px; object-fit:scale-down">

        <input type="file" asp-for="PreviewImageFile" id="preview-image-file" class="preview-image-file" />
        <label class="btn btn-primary" for="preview-image-file">Select file</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Video">Video</label>
            <div asp-for="Video" type="file" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Video" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

a ViewModel code:

```
public class AddUpdateMovieForm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(1024)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IFormFile PreviewImageFile { get; set; }

    public IFormFile Video { get; set; }
}
```

And a controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromForm]AddUpdateMovieForm form)
    {
        var img = form.PreviewImageFile; //always null
        var video = form.Video; // always null
    }
```

When I upload the form PreviewImageFile and Video are null. I've also tryed to upload file withouth a ViewModel, but it is still null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as form attribute for File Upload to work properly.

```
<form asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" id="movie-update-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

</form>
```