# Upload pic to IFromFile to ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I want that the user will upload pic and I want to save it on IFomFile in order to save it in the database.

There is the product controller only the add action get and post, product model, and the the add new view

Product controller:

```
// this is the controler action add new get and post
public IActionResult AddNew()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddNew(ProductModel model)
{
    Product newProd = new Product
        {
            Titele = model.Titele,
            ShortDescrip = model.ShortDescrip,
            LongDescrip = model.LongDescrip,
            Price = model.Price,
            Date = DateTime.Now
        };

    if (model.FirstPic != null)
    {
        if (model.FirstPic.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                model.FirstPic.CopyTo(ms);
                newProd.FirstPic = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    if (model.SecondPic != null)
    {
        if (model.SecondPic.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                model.SecondPic.CopyTo(ms);
                newProd.SecondPic = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    if (model.ThirdPic != null)
    {
        if (model.ThirdPic.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                model.ThirdPic.CopyTo(ms);
                newProd.ThirdPic = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    return Ok(newProd);
}

public class ProductModel
{
    public string Titele { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescrip { get; set; }
    public string LongDescrip { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public IFormFile FirstPic { get; set; }//pic
    public IFormFile SecondPic { get; set; }//pic
    public IFormFile ThirdPic { get; set; }//pic
}
```

This is the cshtml view

```
<form method="post">
    <div>
        <label asp-for="Titele" style="width:140px">Title:</label><br />
        <input asp-for=" Titele" placeholder="enter Title" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="ShortDescrip" style="width:140px">Short Description:</label><br />
        <input asp-for=" ShortDescrip" placeholder="enter Short Description" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="LongDescrip" style="width:140px">Long Description:</label><br />
        <textarea asp-for=" LongDescrip" placeholder="enter Short Description"style="width:140px" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="Price" >Price:</label><br />
        <input asp-for=" Price" placeholder="enter price" type="number" min="0" step="0.1"/>
    </div>   
    <div>
        <label asp-for="FirstPic" style="width:140px">first pic:</label><br />
        <input asp-for=" FirstPic" placeholder="enter Pic" type="file" accept="image/*" />
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstPic"></span>
    </div>   
    <div>
        <label asp-for="SecondPic" style="width:140px">Second pic:</label><br />
        <input asp-for=" SecondPic" placeholder="enter Pic" type="file" accept=".png, .jpg" />
    </div>  
    <div>
        <label asp-for="ThirdPic" style="width:140px">Third pic:</label><br />
        <input asp-for=" ThirdPic" placeholder="enter Pic" type="file" accept=".png, .jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="upload" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks to all helpers - if needed more code just say

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2jVs.jpg)
pic that shows that after upload it stil null on ifromfile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYKqP.jpg)upload the pic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IFormFile properties in viewmodel null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437951/iformfile-properties-in-viewmodel-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after upload it stil null on ifromfile

If you are using HTML form that has file upload input(s), you must [specify an encoding type (`enctype`) of `multipart/form-data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype) for your HTML form.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

For more information, please check this official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#null-reference-exception-with-iformfile